# Add self signed certificate in Ubuntu Core 16.04

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-core, docker

I need to add a self-signed certificate for a private Docker registry into Ubuntu Core 16.04.

The standard Ubuntu way of doing is to add the certificate in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and run `update-ca-certificates` to update the system, as explained here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

In the previous version of Ubuntu Core I was able to remount the filesystem in read/write mode and use the standard Ubuntu way, but in Ubuntu Core 16.04 the filesystem is squashfs.

How is it possible to add the certificate in 16.04?